# Cell spanning multiple columns in table using python-docx

Tags: python, openxml, python-docx

I'm trying to create a table that looks like this, using the [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) module.

[image: Example of the table I want to create]

Working from the example code for creating a table in example-makedocument.py and reading through the code in docx.py, I thought something similar to this would work:

```
tbl_rows = [ ['A1'], 
       ['B1', 'B2' ],
       ['C1', 'C2' ] ]
tbl_colw = [ [100],
       [25, 75],
       [25, 75] ]
tbl_cwunit = 'pct'

body.append(table(tbl_rows, colw=tbl_colw, cwunit=tbl_cwunit))
```

however this corrupts the docx document, and when Word recovers the document the table is shown as this:

[image: Actual table created]

How can I get a row to properly span multiple columns using python-docx?

Comment: I don't know in Python, but in C# you need to give the `TableCell` a `GridSpan` instance. EDIT: looking at the source code, it doesn't seem like you can do this with python-docx.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm working out how to do this using lxml directly, should be able to add an answer soon.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to work on it lately (other priorities). I'll make an update here if I manage to chip away at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a merge_cells() function to the row class of python-docx, that can merge any cells on a single row. I'm hoping it will get included in python-docx. In the meantime, you can grab it from [my github "merge_cells_feature" python-docx branch](https://github.com/Apteryks/python-docx/tree/merge_cells_feature).

I'm copying the example I wrote on [the pull request](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/pull/82) here for reference:

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document()
table = doc.add_table(6,6)
header_row = table.rows[0]
header_row.merge_cells()

# args can also be passed to merge_cells(mergeStart, mergeStop) in order to 
# implement any kind of merge on the same row, such as:
table.rows[1].merge_cells(0,3)  # This will merge the cells indexed from 0 to 2.
```

Comment: Following discussions with the python-docx maintainer, another, more complete implementation was made. It's being hosted here: https://github.com/Apteryks/python-docx/tree/cell-merge_feature. Any table cell now has a 'merge' method which takes another table cell as argument. It can merge both horizontally, vertically, or both.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for this answer to be accepted.

Comment: Github link is no longer valid.

Comment: @LMc: I must have deleted that branch since the feature got merged in. That is good news, but the API differs a bit, since it can merge in both directions. Suppose that you have a 3x3 table and would like to merge the first row, you could do: `my_table.cell(0, 0).merge(my_table.cell(0, 2))` if I remember correctly.