# Create multiindex from existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, reindex

I've spent hours browsing everywhere now to try to create a multiindex from dataframe in pandas. This is the dataframe I have (posting excel sheet mockup. I do have this in pandas dataframe):

[image: have]

And this is what I want:

[image: want]

I have tried

```
newmulti = currentDataFrame.set_index(['user_id','account_num'])
```

But it returns a dataframe, not a multiindex. Also, I could not figure out how to make 'user_id' level 0 and 'account_num' level 1. I think this must be trivial but I've read so many posts, tutorials, etc. and still could not figure it out. Partly because I'm a very visual person and most posts are not. Please help!

Comment: For processing purposes, both the tables are the same. But for display purposes, I suggest you to refer to: [stackoverflow.com/a/25127764/2306662](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25127764/2306662)

Comment: But I thought I need multi-index if, say I want to plot total sales (of all account) vs. dates?

Comment: @puifais why can't you plot the second dataframe you've put together?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could simply use `groupby` in this case, which will create the multi-index automatically when it sums the sales along the requested columns.

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'account_num', 'dates']).sales.sum().to_frame()
```

You should also be able to simply do this:

```
df.set_index(['user_id', 'account_num', 'dates'])
```

Although you probably want to avoid any duplicates (e.g. two or more rows with identical `user_id`, `account_num` and `date` values but different sales figures) by summing them, which is why I recommended using `groupby`.

If you need the multi-index, you can simply access viat `new_df.index` where `new_df` is the new dataframe created from either of the two operations above.

And `user_id` will be level 0 and `account_num` will be level 1.

Comment: So this means, group by user_id, account_num, and dates and pull out sales data. if sales data so happen to have the same user_id, account_num, and dates, then sum them. is that right?

Comment: Sort of... It means you are aggregating the sales data via `sum`.  If the column was not numeric, you wouldn't be able to sum it.  You would have to use something like `first`, `last` or `unique` with a lambda function.

Comment: What if I have more columns, other than sales?

Answer (score 8):

For clarification of future users I would like to add the following:

As said by Alexander,

```
df.set_index(['user_id', 'account_num', 'dates'])
```

with a possible `inplace=True` does the job.

The `type(df)` gives

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

whereas `type(df.index)` is indeed the expected

```
pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html)

```
lvl0 = currentDataFrame.user_id.values
lvl1 = currentDataFrame.account_num.values

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([lvl0, lvl1], names=['level 0', 'level 1'])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do it, albeit not exactly like you have shown, but it works.
Say you have the following df:

```
      A   B    C      D
0   nil one    1    NaN
1   bar one    5    5.0
2   foo two    3    8.0
3   bar three  2    1.0
4   foo two    4    2.0
5   bar two    6    NaN
```

**1. Workaround 1:**

`df.set_index('A', append = True, drop = False).reorder_levels(order = [1,0]).sort_index()`

This will return:

[image]

**2. Workaround 2:**

`df.set_index(['A', 'B']).sort_index()`

This will return:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The DataFrame returned by `currentDataFrame.set_index(['user_id','account_num'])` has it's index set to `['user_id','account_num']`

`newmulti.index` will return the MultiIndex object.

Comment: Um...I don't understand. So do I do `newmulti = currentDataFrame.set_index(['user_id','account_num'])` and then `newmultiReal = newmulti.index`? Would you please clarify? I'm totally new at pandas.

Comment: What is your end goal? If you want the original dataframe with a multiindex, you've already got it.